# How to give "locations" to CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, core-graphics, linear-gradients, cagradientlayer

I have created `CAGradientLayer` having three colors, i need to give each color different locations.
Example:

```
Red = 0 to 50 %
Yellow = 51 to 80 %
Green = 81 to 100 %
```

I have tried with giving `startPoint` and `endPoint` but it did not work.[image]

Comment: where exactly are you struggling? The layer has two properties `colors` and `locations` that should be of use for you. What language btw?

Comment: Your "example" is not clear, explain what exactly 0%-50%, 51%-80% and 81%-100% mean and add the code you used so that someone could show you the problem, otherwise all we can do is to quote documentation.

Comment: The color on the gradient layer should be such and such percentage, by default all three colors will distribute evenly which I want to change. I am using Objective-C.
Thank you.

Comment: It would be great if someone explains how "location" property of CAGradientLayer works for three or more colors.

Comment: @SunilRao I wrote an answer using your exact percentages.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you put the following code into a Playground you will get the exact desired output:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,100))

let layer = CAGradientLayer()
layer.frame = view.frame
layer.colors = [UIColor.greenColor().CGColor, UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor, UIColor.redColor().CGColor]
layer.locations = [0.0, 0.8, 1.0]

view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

XCPShowView("ident", view: view)
```

Outputting:

[image]

You simply define the colors as an array of `CGColors`, and an array of the same size of `NSNumber`s each between 0.0 and 1.0.

Dont use `startPoint` and `endPoint` for that - they are for defining from where to where the gradient is shown in the layer - it does not have anything to do with the percents and the colors etc.

---

More recent Swift3 version of the code:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
let layer = CAGradientLayer()
layer.frame = view.frame
layer.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
layer.locations = [0.0, 0.8, 1.0]
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: @luk What if I want a horizontal gradient using locations array?

Comment: Thanks for the replay @luk2302 , We can use startpoint,endpoint and locations together to make horizontal gradient.

Comment: @abhi1992 that sounds right, it seems like that is exactly the use for those properties, will keep that in mind